# Let ash pick up /home/user/.profile when invoked as non-interactive shell

Tags: docker, busybox, dash

I have an Alpine-based container that offers `sshd` for an account `user`. The container's `/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys` invokes a specific command:

```
command="ash -lc /usr/local/bin/command.sh" ssh-rsa ...
```

`command.sh` should pick up environment variables from `/home/user/.profile`. `/home/user/.bashrc` would be [better suited](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell), but since Alpine uses `ash` I [use `-l`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412844) to let it act as if it had been invoked as a login shell.

What I observe when connecting to my container with `ssh user@...` (and e.g. dump environment variables with `set` in `command.sh`) is that the environment variables are apparently not picked up as expected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched the image's base image from `alpine` to `debian`, and there the issue went away because of the availability of `/home/user/.profile`.